# send_keys with ActionChains don't work when I put value in field

Tags: python, selenium

> the cursor is in the active window from the very beginning, but the input into the field does not occur. There is no way to use find_element for the input, I try switching fields through the TAB button.
> the site itself and its form open normally

**url I'm working with:**
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth

**full code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


class TestLogin:
    driver = ''

    def setup_method(self):
        self.driver =        webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\WORK\PycharmProjects\at\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
        self.driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth')

    def test_login(self):
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)

        # user name
        action.send_keys(Keys, "admin")
        # move to next field
        action.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
        # password
        action.send_keys("admin")
        # try to login
        action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        action.perform()
        # check login
        self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(), 'Congratulations!')]")

    def teardown_method(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of handling basic authentication in selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

user = 'admin'
passw = 'admin'
browser.get(f"https://{user}:{passw}@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")

test_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(), 'Congratulations!')]")))

print(test_element.text)
```

This will print in terminal:

```
Congratulations! You must have the proper credentials.
```

You can include the logic above in your unit test classes (or rethink your logic and get rid of unnecessary OOPing everything) - your call.

Comment: thank you for your answer and recommendations  ! :)